# MATLAB: change BaseValue on semilog bar chart

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How can I change the base value on the following barchart from 0 to another value (eg 0.001)? Right now it looks plain silly:

[image: Ridiculous bar chart contrapted in MATLAB]

Code:

```
h=bar(matrix);
set(gca,'YScale','log')
```

Bonus points / good karma for changing x-values to text!

Cheers

Comment: To anser the karma part: set(gca,'XTick',1:1:1)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'Text','Goes','Here'})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the option to change the `baseValue` property of bar plots came out only in a later version of Matlab (which version do you have?), but the following works for me:

```
%# create bar plot with horizontal line at 3
bar(randn(4),'baseValue',1)
%# rename x-tick labels
set(gca,'xticklabel',{'first','second','third'})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Found [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1200) on the file exchange. It seems like what you want.

<strike>[This thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/16208) covers your problem. It seems like an ugly hack. The thread does not point to a nice and built-in way to address your problem.</strike>